# Why does string mehod str.format(value) have different default padding with empty strings for integer values and string values?

Tags: python, python-3.7

Why is str.format() padding from left for integers but right for strings by default? It doesn't make sense to me why wouldn't there be just one default padding for both integers and strings.

For example, in case value is a string it's centered to the left:

```
>>> "{value:20}".format(value="Guido van Rossum")
'Guido van Rossum    '
>>> "{value:>20}".format(value="Guido van Rossum")
'    Guido van Rossum'
```

but in case value is an integer it's centered to the right by default:

```
>>> "{value:20}".format(value=8)
'                   8'
>>> "{value:<20}".format(value=8)
'8                   '
```

I would expect it to work the same for integer value as well as string value. What's the need for this behavior?

Comment: Cross-site and language duplicate: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/13795/is-there-a-standard-to-left-justify-text-and-right-justify-numeric-values .

Comment: It is normal for numbers to be right-aligned. Think of your bank statement. Would you really want to see a column of transactions with the numbers left-aligned? Equally, it is normal for strings (at least in languages that read left to right) to be left aligned. The difference in the default puts an ordinary programmer's expectations ahead of mechanical uniformity. Maybe you expect it to work the same for integers and strings. But most people don't.

Answer (score 2):

This should probably be closed as off-topic or opinion-based, because you know as well as we do that the technical answer is "because that's what the function's designer chose".

But fwiw, this formatting convention is VERY common.  Open up excel.  Drag a column out to be rather wide.  Type a short numeric value in one cell in that column, and a short string in another.

If that isn't the behavior you need, use `<` or `>` to ensure consistent padding per your needs.  If it isn't what you'd expect, I don't know what to tell you other than to adjust your expectations, because that is the documented behavior of the function.

Comment: Checkout out my link - it's more than common, it's "standard".

Comment: @kabanus - "it's standard" is a meaningless phrase.  There are many standards, and if the documentation said that `format` would, by default, left-pad all values, then that behavior would be just as correct.  The common practice that was chosen was the chosen practice - that's all there is to it.

Comment: Completely disagree. It is not always the case that there are "many standards". In this specific case it is near ubiquitous. A language designer could go against this standard, but for some reason, most do not. This of course says nothing to the correctness of anything, just what you might expect.